# Relate a continuous inner product to a discrete one by expanding a kernel around a Dirac delta function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, signal-processing

I am trying to find the discrepancy between an integral and a discrete approximation.

The "ideal" inner product between two signals $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is an integral,
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_\text{continuous} \equiv \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx.$$

However, in my application, $f$ and $g$ are somehow discretized, for example, by averaging within windows of width $\Delta$ centered on the points $x=x_k\equiv k\Delta$, for $k = 0, \pm1, \pm2 ,\ldots$:
$$
f_k \equiv \frac{1}{\Delta}\int\limits_{x_k-\Delta/2}^{x_k+\Delta/2} f(x) dx,
$$
and similarly for $g$.

A discrete version of the inner product is then
$$
\langle f , g \rangle_\text{discrete} \equiv \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_k g_k \Delta.
$$

When $\Delta \to 0$ the discrete version should converge to the continuous version. I would like to find the error when the bins are small but not zero-width. I imagine there should be some kind of expansion like
$$
\langle f , g \rangle_\text{discrete} = \langle f , g \rangle_\text{continuous} + (\text{something}) \Delta + (\text{something}) \Delta^2 + \cdots.
$$

How can I find the (something)'s?

---

**Thoughts about how proceed:**
My gut feeling is that the expansion should be independent of the functions $f$ and $g$ and comes from something like the Taylor expansion of a kernel operator around the Dirac delta function.

I'm not sure the best way to formulate the above statement concretely in "linear operator language". Discretizing from $f(x)$ to $f_k$ can be thought of as applying a window operator to the original $f$. The operator uses a kernel $W_\Delta$ to map a function on $\mathbb{R}$ to a function on $\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
(W_\Delta f)_k = f_k = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty W_\Delta(x_k - x) f(x) dx,
$$
where $W_\Delta(x)$ is a top hat kernel equal to $1/\Delta$ between $-\Delta/2$ and  $\Delta/2$ and zero otherwise.

The two inner products can be written as kernels as well. Something like,
\begin{align}
\langle f, g \rangle_\text{continuous} &= f^\dagger \, K_c \, g \\
\langle f, g \rangle_\text{discrete} &= (W_\Delta f)^\dagger \, K_\Delta \, (W_\Delta g),
\end{align}
where the continuous inner product kernel $K_c$ is the delta function $\delta(x-y)$.

Then my question is asking how expand the "discretizing inner product operator",
$$
W_\Delta ^\dagger K_\Delta W_\Delta
$$
in powers of $\Delta$. I think the lowest order term should be the Dirac delta function. And the ${O}(\Delta^n)$ term will be some new kernel I can apply to the continuous $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: This question reminds me a bit of the [Abel Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) and the [Euler Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) but I'm not sure if either can be applied in this case.

Comment: Maybe there is an advantage in viewing this as a $L^2$ martingale and see if some convergence theorem yields the desired result. I am not sure how to get the type of error terms that you want though.